# How to have both background effect and position fixed

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div which is holding links called `#linkHolder`. I have its `position:fixed`. The links have a background which have a `background-attachment: fixed` to give it that nice background effect. Those two things seem to cancel each other out. Is there a way around this issue?

```css
#linkHolder {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #1b242f;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Sansita Swashed";
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 6%;
}

#homeLink {
  background-image: url("/static/portfolioBackground/linkBackA.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="linkHolder">
  <ul>
    <li><a id="homeLink" href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a id="aboutLink" href="/about">About</a></li>
    <li><a id="serviceLink" href="service">Services</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the issue on codepen I am having.
https://codepen.io/webdev154676/pen/VwjNoRN

Here's what I would like to have with the background image, but with the #linkHolder as position fixed, it will not work. Please help, and thank you for your time.
https://codepen.io/webdev154676/pen/rNLgBVv

Comment: don't repeat the same question

Answer (score 1):

From your question I'm understanding that the issue is that the background image is a little more blurred than what you would like to have.

For that i sudjest you to try using the `background-size` attribute and play around with it giving some sizes in % like

```
#homeLink{
background-size:90% 100%;
}
```

Comment: This not a duplicate! Was this a user or the A.I that decided this!

Comment: @Anthony A user i think, but as it seems that's a Duplicate of your own question no?

Comment: I could not delete or edit the other question. I decided to use codepen this time. When scrolling the image stays in place and gives this nice background image affect, but I can't do that with the parent div as a fixed position.

Comment: If i didn’t understood the question right try to make an example where the problem is completely clear :) right now i dont really get where it is.. Maybe add some scrolling that make it clear or something like that ! Update me when u’r done!